# Declare everything after a character

Tags: python, blender

I'm trying to write a Python script for Blender that will delete all shape keys that have `KK` at the start of them.

I have many `shapekeys` which start with `KK` but have different stuff after `KK`, for example `KK_Eyebrows` or `KK_Nose`

I managed to use this:

```py
import bpy

def deleteShapekeyByName(oObject, sShapekeyName):
    
    # setting the active shapekey
    iIndex = oObject.data.shape_keys.key_blocks.keys().index(sShapekeyName)
    oObject.active_shape_key_index = iIndex
    
    # delete it
    bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove()

oActiveObject = bpy.context.active_object
deleteShapekeyByName(oActiveObject, "KK_Shapekey")
```

But I have to manually put in every `shapekey` name I want to remove, instead of removing everything that has `KK` in it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can get a list of the shapekey names you can do something like this.

```
import bpy

def deleteShapekeyByName(oObject, sShapekeyName):
    
    # setting the active shapekey
    iIndex = oObject.data.shape_keys.key_blocks.keys().index(sShapekeyName)
    oObject.active_shape_key_index = iIndex
    
    # delete it
    bpy.ops.object.shape_key_remove()
    
# Not sure if this returns the right keys for you. you may have to change .object to .active_object
s_key_names = list(bpy.context.object.data.shape_keys.key_blocks.keys())
oActiveObject = bpy.context.active_object

for s_k_n in s_key_names:

    if s_k_n.startswith('KK'):

        deleteShapekeyByName(oActiveObject, s_k_n)
```

Comment: how would i use it? Ive never used python before so im having trouble figuring it out ^^"

Comment: Do you have a list of all the shapekey names?

Comment: If you mean in the script, then no. Other than the list under the Shape keys tab in blender to the side, i dont have any lists

Comment: Ok, i updated my answer with an implementation of the code. Im not sure if I got the right list of shapekeys though

Comment: You're welcome! I'm glad it worked! If you could accept the answer that would be appreciated :)